# T-SQL syntax error when executing a stored procedure passing in a datetime variable as a varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My sql code is below:

```
 EXEC spMyStoredProcedure
   @StartDateTime='' + CONVERT(varchar(25), @today_date,121) + '',
   @EndDateTime=@today_date,
   @MaxDateTime='9999-12-31 23:59:59.997';
```

However, when I execute this in MSSQLServer Management Studio 2012, I see the following error in the message section:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it would be better to pass datetime as datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define separate variable, set its value according to your needs and pass it as argument of stored procedure:

```
declare @date varchar(100)
select @date = '' + CONVERT(varchar(25), @today_date,121) + ''

EXEC spMyStoredProcedure
 @StartDateTime=@date,
 @EndDateTime=@today_date,
 @MaxDateTime='9999-12-31 23:59:59.997';
```

This is required because when you're calling stored procedure, all of this procedure parameters should be one of: constant values, variable name or `DEFAULT` keyword, but **not expressions**.

See [EXEC MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. That's not a valid syntax

```
DECLARE @st VARCHAR(20) = '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @today_date, 121) + ''

EXEC Spmystoredprocedure
  @StartDateTime=@st,
  @EndDateTime=@today_date,
  @MaxDateTime='9999-12-31 23:59:59.997';
```